# Disaster recovery solution for MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, percona

I have set a Master-master replication with the second Master running as read-only. This master-master setup is on the same location. Now I will have to setup an DR for this production at a different location. What are the solutions I have? Is it possible to set another master-master setup at DR site where in the Master in DR acts as the slave of the active master of DC? Will that work? Any other inputs for DR solution would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Active-Passive master-master is a good setup but I have seen SUPER (humans)users writing on slave without setting sql_log_bin. 
(Though [super_read_only](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_super_read_only) in 5.7 will change things around this.)

Anyways, following is possible and works.

```
ProdActiveMaster<---->ProdPassiveMaster
|
|
|
\/
DRmaster----->DRSlave
```

So you know now that another master-master setup is not possible as DRMaster cannot replicate from two masters.
I doubt multi-source replication is a solution here as it will create more trouble than help.

You need to make sure to keep your DRSlave, "master-ready"... setting auto_increment% and binlog + logslaveupdates settings.

Comment: Okay but why do you say DR master cannot replicate from two masters? trying to understand the reason here. Is Master-master not possible in DR also?

Comment: There can only be one source. If DRMaster replicates from ProductionMaster, it cannot replicate from DRSlave!

Comment: Newer versions working towards multi-source replication but it will switch between maters. In our scneario, if DRMaster switches from ProdMaster (which is actually the only source of data) to DRSlave, we will be lagging. Thus increase risk a possible data loss in case disaster.

Percona, MariaDB and MySQL 5.7 all provides multi-source replication. You may google, here is one link to refer: http://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-5-7-6-introducing-multi-source-replication/

Comment: Alright got it. So this is the possible setup that I can have right as DR solution? do you think any other DR features that can be setup?

Comment: But we stick to Percona's 5.6 and not 5.7 so we cannot go for multi-source.

Comment: You don't need multi-source here (even if it's possible) so you don't need to bother  about it. 

Backups are even more important. A drop database on ProdMaster will leave you no option of recovery without backup with your this DR(/ "HA-failover")-setup! 
Where do you do Backups? How often? Do you backup binary logs (need point in time recovery)? Are they saved in remote location as well (this is important)? etc...

Comment: At-times people use Delayed Replication as well to avoid such huge-data-change-risks (drop database as mentioned)! 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html

Comment: we do take daily backups of the databases but not the binary logs. it stays on disk and goes to the tape as well. We take backups from Prodmaster. DR is not setup yet. about to start those.

Comment: You should not backup from ProdActiveMaster but ProdPassiveMaster.

Comment: the below answer says master master in DR is also possible.. the same question which I had asked you.

Comment: DR master cannot replicate simultaneously from ProdMaster as well as DRSlave. (unless it's multi-source replication)...........
 
If that was possible then no-one would have bothered about multi-source as a new feature... don't you think??

Comment: DR setup with percona cluster could include nodes from different data centers. But there is no concept of master-master in cluster. (Just saying what you might already know)

Comment: Here is the condition in @greenlitmysql's comment you might have missed --> "**upon failover.**".

Answer (score 1):

Master Master should be possible in DR too. Basically what you really have is a Master - Slave with Slave ready to become a master upon failover.
So in 
Location 1: Master Active <--> Macter Passive 
Location 2: Master Active <--> Macter Passive 
Master Active in Location 1 should replicate to Master Active in Location 2.
Make sure they all have bin logs turned on, and update slave.
I've done similar set up with Percona Cluster.

Comment: Im using percona server but not the cluster. Is it possible do the way you mentioned? ProdMaster to DRMaster?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just make sure Master passive is ready only. Technically you don't have to ; read only is to guarantee no writes can occur and break replication. But you could have a database on Master Passive that does not exist anywhere else and write to it without affecting replication. I hope this makes sense.